# inputs is not used in models, only in loss raise error when save model! (tf.2.0-beta1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

this is a simple version of my real model

```
def mae_loss(y_true,y_pred):
      return tf.reduce_mean(keras.losses.mae(y_true,y_pred))
np.random.seed(2)
a = np.random.rand(1000,10)
b = np.random.rand(1000,1)
inputs1 = keras.Input(shape=(10,))
inputs2 = keras.Input(shape=(1,))
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs1)
model = keras.Model((inputs1,inputs2),outputs)
model.add_loss(mae_loss(inputs2,outputs))
model.compile('adam')
ck = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('best-test.h5',save_best_noly=True)
model.fit((a,b),epochs=10,validation_data=((a,b),None),callbacks=[ck])
```

> ValueError: Could not pack sequence. Structure had 2 elements, but
>   flat_sequence had 1 elements.  Structure: (, ), flat_sequence:
>   [].

Comment: Please have a short look at other questions to see that the title should be short and most of what is now in your title should go to the body of the question. This way you might better attract the attention of people that can actually solve your problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Please post a minimal version of your code which regenerates your error. Current code doesn't produce any error and save checkpoint successfully in tf 2.0.

Comment: I known the reason, it was caused by tf-2.0-beta1. After I updated tf to 2.0.0(latest) version，the code worked well! Whatever,thank you very much!

Comment: how does the code works with a typo though , "save_best_noly"?